# vector add and dot in eigen do not accelerate by mkl

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3, intel-mkl, eigenvector

Here is the code I use:

```
#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL

#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    VectorXf a = VectorXf::Random(100000000); 
    VectorXf b = VectorXf::Random(100000000);

    double start = clock();
    VectorXf c = a+b;
    float d = a.dot(b);
    double endd = clock();
    double thisTime = (double)(endd - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << thisTime << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with mkl:

```
g++ mkl_test.cpp /home/tong.guo/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so -Ieigen -Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread -lm -ldl -m64 -I/home/tong.guo/intel/mkl/include
```

Remove the first line of code and compile without mkl:

```
g++ mkl_test.cpp -Ieigen
```

The time are almost same.

But matrix computation can be accelerated.
Change the code to below I can see the speed.

```
    MatrixXd a = MatrixXd::Random(1000, 1000);  
    MatrixXd b = MatrixXd::Random(1000, 1000);

    double start = clock();
    MatrixXd c = a * b;   
    double endd = clock();
    double thisTime = (double)(endd - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << thisTime << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [eigen page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html) on enabling mkl:

> EIGEN_USE_BLAS Enables the use of external BLAS level 2 and 3 routines

Eigen won't use external routines here since vector adds and dot products are level 1 blas routines.

Comment: EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL Defines EIGEN_USE_BLAS, EIGEN_USE_LAPACKE, and EIGEN_USE_MKL_VML